# To convert multi level to hierarchy inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

When I tried to convert it the class result can't get the data from class marks even if I made the data variables of marks public I don't know why. I also declared a object of class marks in result and then tried to access it but failed again I am new to coding so don't know all the syntax correctly your help will be of great use

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class student {
 private:
  int rl;
  char nm[20];

 public:
  void read();
  void display();
};

class marks : public student {
 protected:
  int s1;
  int s2;
  int s3;

 public:
  void getmarks();
  void putmarks();
};

class result : public marks {
 private:
  int t;
  float p;
  char div[10];

 public:
  void process();
  void printresult();
};

void student::read() {
  cout << "enter Roll no and Name " << endl;
  cin >> rl >> nm;
}

void student::display() {
  cout << "Roll NO:" << rl << endl;
  cout << "name : " << nm << endl;
}

void marks ::getmarks() {
  cout << "enter three subject marks  " << endl;
  cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;
}

void marks ::putmarks() {
  cout << "subject 1:" << s1 << endl;
  cout << "subject 2 :" << s2 << endl;
  cout << "subject 3:" << s3 << endl;
}

void result::process() {
  t = s1 + s2 + s3;
  p = t / 3.0;
  p >= 60   ? strcpy(div, "first")
  : p >= 50 ? strcpy(div, "second")
            : strcpy(div, "third");
}

void result::printresult() {
  cout << "total = " << t << endl;
  cout << "per  = " << p << "%" << endl;
  cout << "div = " << div << endl;
}

int main(){
  result x;

  x.read();
  x.getmarks();
  x.process();
  x.display();
  x.putmarks();
  x.printresult();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is your problem exactly? The code you previded seems to work as far as I can understand it. Is your problem related to the convertion between objects of type result, marks and student? Could you provide an example which doesn't work and explain what you want it to do?

Comment: Please also indent your code consistently. It makes it easier to read, to understand and to spot possible errors. It should also be a [mcve] for this question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I want to convert this multilevel inheritance to hierarchy inheritance

Comment: @NiteeshKulhari what order do you need the hierarchical inheritance to follow?

Comment: any order is fine by me I just wanna see how to do it

Comment: `class marks : public student` -- `marks` *is-a* `student`?   Does that relationship make sense to you?

Comment: I wanted to do it like.    class marks : public student.       class result : public student

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class marks  // parent class
{
protected:
  int s1;
  int s2;
  int s3;
public:
   void getmarks();
   void putmarks();
};

class student : public marks     // child class
{
private:
  int rl;
  char nm[20];
public:
   void read();
   void display();
};
class result : public marks// child class
{
private:
  int t;
  float p;
  char div[10];
public:
   void process();
   void printresult();
};
   void student::read()
   {
    cout<<"enter Roll no and Name "<<endl;
    cin>>rl>>nm;
   }
   void student:: display()
   {
   cout <<"Roll NO:"<<rl<<endl;
   cout<<"name : "<<nm<<endl;
   }
   void marks ::getmarks()
   {
   cout<<"enter three subject marks  "<<endl;
    cin>>s1>>s2>>s3;
   }
   void marks ::putmarks()
   {
    cout <<"subject 1:"<<s1<<endl;
    cout<<"subject 2 :"<<s2<<endl;
    cout <<"subject 3:"<<s3<<endl;
   }
 
   void result::process()
   {
     t= s1+s2+s3;
     p = t/3.0;
     p>=60?strcpy(div,"first"):p>=50?strcpy(div, "second"): strcpy(div,"third");
   }
 
   void result::printresult()
   {
    cout<<"total = "<<t<<endl;
   cout<<"per  = "<<p<<"%"<<endl;
   cout<<"div = "<<div<<endl;
   }
   int main()
   {
    result x;
    student y;
    
    y.read();
    x.getmarks();
    x.process();
    y.display();
    x.putmarks();
    x.printresult();
    
   }
```